# Create MagicMock that acts like a class object and when instantiated creates a MagicMock instance

Tags: python, python-unittest, pydantic

I have a rather interesting problem. I am trying to mock a class that would pass an internal validation and when instantiated would return a magicmock instance.

Example, I have a pydantic model that validates the fields like:

```py
from typing import Type
from pydantic import BaseModel

class SomeClass:
    pass

class SubSomeClass(SomeClass):
    pass

class OtherClass:
    pass

class SomeModel(BaseModel):
    cls: Type[SomeClass]

# here I can put either `SomeClass` or its subclasses
validated_some = SomeModel(cls=SubSomeClass)

# this would cause ValidationError
SomeModel(cls=OtherClass)
"""
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for SomeModel
cls
  subclass of SomeClass expected (type=type_error.subclass; expected_class=SomeClass)
"""
```

Now in my tests, I am trying to mock my `SomeClass` using `MagicMock`, but I cannot create a mocked *class object* that would act like a subclass of `SomeClass`.

I tried the following:

```py
>>> type(Mock(spec=SomeClass))
<class 'unittest.mock.Mock'> # doesn't pass validation
```

```py
class MockSomeClass(SomeClass, MagicMock):
    """Mocked SomeClass"""

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass
```

Does not return `MagicMock` instance when instantiated i.e. `MockSomeClass()`.

Basically I need something that would act like:

```
>>> type(mocked_some_class)
<class 'type'>
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getmro(mocked_some_class)
(..., <class '__main__.SomeClass'>, ...)
>>> mocked_some_class()
<MagicMock id='...'>
```

Comment: Can you show your actual test? I'm not sure I understand at what point in the test the validation comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing:

```
from unittest.mock import Mock

class MockSomeClass(SomeClass, Mock):
    """Mocked SomeClass class"""

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return MagicMock()
```

And now all checks pass:

```
>>> type(MockSomeClass)
<class 'type'>

>>> inspect.getmro(MockSomeClass)
(<class '__main__.MockSomeClass'>, <class '__main__.SomeClass'>, <class 'unittest.mock.Mock'>, ...)

>>> MockSomeClass()
<MagicMock id='...'>
```

Hope, it'll be useful for someone! :)

Comment: where does the 'Mock' object come from? :) thanks!

Comment: @sg_sg94 hey, sorry I should have added imports. Updated my answer now

Comment: doesn't work for me, I get AttributeError: _mock_methods